# Java DatagramSocket receive() takes more time than send() for the same packet size

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am writing a UDP datagram Server-Client application in which packets of size either 60/100/200 bytes (including UDP+IP+MAC header) are transmitted over high-speed link.  This application is latency critical i.e. each packet should experience the same latency, ideally the round-trip time over the link. However, as packet size increases, a proportional increase in the latency is acceptable.

To this end, I have measured block by block execution time of my code. Strangely, I have observed that, time taken by socket.receive(pkt) is in order of 400-500 microseconds and keeps increasing as the packet size increases. On the other hand, socket. send (pkt) takes 20-100 microseconds. Thus, socket.receive() packet on client and server is causing more than 1 millisecond latency over the actual round-trip time.

Note that, both Server-Client sockets are able to handle the high packet arrival rates and packet loss is not a concern.

I clearly fail to understand, why such a behavior only on receive() function if the packet size is same? Help/discussion is highly appreciated.

Following is the block of code for receiving datagram packets.

```
private void receive() throws Exception {
    receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuffer, inBuffer.length);
    while(true){
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        clientSocket.receive(receivedPacket);
        System.out.println("time to receive "+ TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(System.nanoTime() - t1));
        threadPool.execute(new ClientSend(new DatagramPacket(receivedPacket.getData(), receivedPacket.getLength(), serverAddress, receiverPort)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you test this with two concurrent processes, one pumping out datagrams and another one accepting them? As EJP's answer notes, asynchronous sends and synchronous receives make the question sort of moot...

Comment: In this case, I think your buffer is too big, so maybe the network stack waits that this buffer to fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A send is usually just a transfer into the socket send buffer. The actual sending over the wire is asynchronous. You aren't measuring that.

A receive consists first of blocking if necessary until data is available in the socket receive buffer, then a transfer out of the receive buffer.

They aren't comparable.